# How to get file content from sharepoint 2010 server?

Tags: rest

```
TeamSiteDataContext context = new TeamSiteDataContext(new Uri("http://server/_vti_bin/ListData.svc"));
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
var f = context.SharedDocuments.Where(a => a.Name == "document1.docx").SingleOrDefault();
```

How can I get the content of the file f as a byte array? I am using Webservices Rest Interface for sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you don't have problems to get the SPFile. Here is a little example:

```
SPFile xmlFile = ...


using (var sr = new StreamReader(xmlFile.OpenBinaryStream()))
{
    String xmlString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    ...
}
```

**OpenBinaryStream** gives you back a stream. You will get the naked bytes back ;)

Comment: I am developing a client-side application which accesses data from a remote sharepoint server. From what I googled I found that SPFile class is in Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll which can be used only if the application is on the same server. Am I understanding it correctly? Or do I need to dig in deeper? Other than the rest interface there is also a soap interface which uses the Lists.asmx web service. But that looked a bit complicated to me. Is there a way to get the content using ListData.svc because it is easier to use?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an easy way to do this. Looks like there are different web services to achieve different functionality. I finally added a web reference to

```
http://server/_vti_bin/copy.asmx
```

where server should be replaced by sharepoint server name

Suppose, I give it a name CopyReference

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



namespace Asmx
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            CopyReference.Copy copyService = new CopyReference.Copy();
            copyService.Url = @"http://server/_vti_bin/copy.asmx"; // change    server to your sharepoint server
            copyService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");


            string copySource = @"http://server/Shared Documents/document1.docx"; //location of the file on server
            Console.WriteLine("Here");

            CopyReference.FieldInformation myFieldInfo = new  CopyReference.FieldInformation();
            CopyReference.FieldInformation[] myFieldInfoArray = { myFieldInfo };
            byte[] myByteArray;
            Console.WriteLine("Here");

            copyService.GetItem(copySource, out myFieldInfoArray, out myByteArray);
            Console.WriteLine(myByteArray.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();


        }
     }
}
```

myByteArray will give you the bytes in the document.

Comment: Great that the webservice approach is working for you :) Be careful where you store your username and password and don't send it through an unsecure connection.